# AngularJS Factory variable value assignment breaks binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory, angularjs-bindings

It seems that when I assign a new value to a variable in my service/factory it breaks the binding and the controller stops updating the value UNLESS I call the `$scope.verify` function in my controller which merely prints the service object to the console, then the binding updates once. Am I assigning the value wrong in the `skypeClient` factory?

```
property.changed(function (_status) {
                state = _status;
                console.log("New State" + state);
            });
```

Ex. I execute `$scope.signIn()` and and the binding updates to `signingIn` but when the value changes to `SignedIn` (verified with console) the controller doesnt update to `SignedIn` unless I execute `$scope.verify()` for every change in `skypeClient.state` from there on after.

See code below:

**Controller**

```
controller('loginCntrl', function ($scope,skypeClient) {
    $scope.skypeClient = skypeClient;
    $scope.signIn = function () {$scope.skypeClient.signIn($scope.user, $scope.password)}
    $scope.signOut = function(){$scope.skypeClient.signOut()}
    $scope.verify = function () {
        console.log(skypeClient);
        console.log($scope.skypeClient);
    }
});
```

**Service**

```
.factory('skypeClient', function () {
        //Service Properties
        var client = new Skype.Web.Model.Application;
        var state = 'SignedOut';
        var property = property = client.signInManager.state;
        //Initialize Listeners
        var init = function () {
            client.signInManager.state.when('SignedIn', function () {
                console.log('Signin:' + state); // This outputs the correct value
            });
            property.changed(function (_status) {
                state = _status;                  //<--WHERE VALUE IS UPDATED
                console.log("New State" + state);
            });
           }
        //Signin Function
        var signIn = function (username, password) {
           client.signInManager.signIn({
                username: username,
                password: password
            }).then(function () {console.log('LoggedIn');});
        }
        var signOut = function () {
            client.signInManager.signOut()
            .then(function () {
                this.isSignedIn = false;
            }, function (error) {
                this.erros.push(error);
                this.errorCount++;
            });
        }
        init();
        return {
            signIn: signIn,
            signOut, signOut,
            state: function(){return state}
        }
   });
```

**HTML**

```
(Current Signin State: {{skypeClient.state()}} )
```

Comment: @Matt thank you for the edits, Ill make sure to format as such in the future.

Comment: No worries. This is meant to be a collaborative effort and I am glad to see you strive for constant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try this out.

If you can, try to make the state a variable on the scope where it needs to show up in the binding.

**Controller**

```
controller('loginCntrl', function ($scope,skypeClient) {
    ...
    $scope.state = skypeClient.state();
    ...
});
```

**HTML**

```
(Current Signin State: {{ state }} )
```

Now, in your controller, you can add a $watch to the state variable from the skypeClient. If I'm correct, things should update with much more success.

**Controller (again)**

```
controller('loginCntrl', function ($scope,skypeClient) {
    ...
    $scope.state = skypeClient.state();
    ...
    // Add this $watch

    $scope.$watch(skypeClient.state, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            $scope.state = newValue;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! However I seem to still have the same issue with this method, it updates once but after that the binding seems to be broken. If it helps the watch appears to only trigger the first time the value changes.

Comment: @strspl Add a console.log in the function for $watch. What are newValue and oldValue set to after the first time?